# Sliding interface like Workout App on apple watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Does anyone know how to achieve a sliding panel like that on the workout app?  When you start a workout the bottom panel slides like pages but only the bottom part slides not the whole screen.  How is this achieved? I can't seem to find anything that can do this?

Answer (score 3):

***Please note: my original answer to this question applied to watchOS 1. With watchOS 2 & 3, Apple radically improved what we can do in watch apps. I have not yet determined whether the OP's original objective is now possible.***

---

In short, I don't think you can accomplish what you want. I believe Apple is using undocumented calls throughout the app.

---

Longer explanation...

I don't mean to answer your question with another question, but have you determined how to replicate the behavior the Workout app demonstrates when you select the workout you want to do?

For example, if you select "Outdoor Cycle," the subsequent interface controller (the one you are asking about) presents as an odd hybrid between `pushControllerWithName:context:` and `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:`.

[image: Workout - Outdoor Cycle - Distance]

The "< Outdoor Cycle" title paired with the current time is how `pushControllerWithName:context:` renders the pushed controller. In contrast, `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:` is the mechanism for displaying a set of "paged" controllers. Also, as far as I know there is no mechanism to change the global tint color of a Watch app, yet that is exactly what happens when you swipe left and right on the pages you are asking about.

[image: Workout - Outdoor Cycle - Elapsed Time]

It’s a tad more subtle, but if you tap “Outdoor Cycle” in the Workout list, you’ll notice the pages you’re asking about appear with a slick animation that changing “Outdoor Cycle” to “Start”. This behavior cannot be replicated with `presentControllerWithNames:contexts:`, as it always slides the modal interface up from the bottom of the screen.

Obviously, most of the above fails to directly address your question. It more addresses the stuff that makes the controllers you’re asking about appear. I go through all of this to demonstrate that Apple is clearly using undocumented functionality in its pre-installed apps.

More directly addressing your question:

1. There is no mechanism to change the global tint color of a Watch app, yet that is exactly what happens when you swipe left and right on the pages you are asking about.
2. There is no notion of a “UIContainerView” (AKA adding a child view controller) in `WKInterfaceController`. Again, this is exactly the behavior demonstrated in the Workout app.
3. The table of Workouts that you tap to make the controllers you ask about appear is an example of hierarchical navigation, whereas the screens you ask about are an example of page-based navigation. This directly contradicts the statement, “For Watch apps with more than one screen of content, you must choose a technique for navigating between different screens. Watch apps support two navigation styles, **which are mutually exclusive**.” (Emphasis mine.) ([WatchKit Programming Guide: Interface Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html))

---

Hopefully, it goes without saying that I would *love* to be incorrect about any or all of the above. If I am, please school me!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I was kind of hoping there was some trick that I may have missed.